# File "/struts-tags" not found in Struts 1.3

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I wrote a conditional `if else` tag inside a `logic:iterate` in jsp as below:-

```
<s:if test="%{#status=='Scheduling'}">
<td><input type="button" name="Save" enabled="enabled" value="View Log" class="Button" onclick="javascript:update('<bean:write  name="test" property="listName" />','<bean:write name="test" property="testType" />',<bean:write  name="test" property="status" />,this.value)"></td>
</s:if>

<s:elseif test="%{#status=='Running'}">
<td><input type="button" name="Save" enabled="enabled" value="View Log" class="Button" onclick="javascript:update('<bean:write  name="test" property="listName" />','<bean:write name="test" property="testType" />',<bean:write  name="test" property="status" />,this.value)"></td>                
</s:elseif>

<s:else>
<td><input type="button" name="Save" disabled="disabled" value="View Log" class="Button" onclick="javascript:update('<bean:write  name="test" property="listName" />','<bean:write name="test" property="testType" />',<bean:write  name="test" property="status" />,this.value)"></td>                   
</s:else>
```

I defined a `<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` in the beginning of the jsp file as shown below:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

When I am opening the jsp file i am getting the following errors. Could you help me in resolving this?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: File "/struts-tags" not found
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:409)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:116)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:160)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:429)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:492)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1439)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:137)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:170)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:332)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:299)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:317)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing the Struts 1.3 tags with the Struts 2 tags. In order for your taglib declaration `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>` to compile, you must include the `struts2-core-2.1.6.jar` (latest jar at the time of writing) in your `WEB-INF\lib` folder, Struts 2 `struts-tags.tld` is found under (struts2-core-2.1.6.jar\META-INF\struts-tags.tld).

Bear in mind that Struts 2 is **never** backward compatible with Struts 1 as it's a completely new architecture Apache has taken new direction from Struts 1.

I suggest using JSTL instead of using Struts 2 taglib definitions as Struts 1.3 works well with JSTL.

Comment: im using struts 1.3 only,i dont want to work with struts 2,could you suggest the code for JSTL in this context.

Comment: @user756993, you can use `<c:if>` tag or `<c:choose>` (`<c:when>` & `<c:otherwise>`) tags for your conditional tag flows.

Answer (score 0):

in your deployment descriptor, that is web.xml, you should have something like the following declared. (remember to have the tld files in your that taglib-location)

```
   <jsp-config>
     <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-uri>
       <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
     </taglib>
   </jsp-config>
```